# Regular expression to extract a value from a given string

Tags: json, regex, string

I need a regular expression to extract a value from a given key/value pair. It's not for a specific language. A working example in https://regex101.com/ would be great.

Here's what I get:

> {"task_id":"12323232-323-23-321"}

and here's what I expect:

> 12323232-323-23-321

I know, it looks easy, but drives me crazy.

The perfect solution would be:

> "return the value for task_id"

.

Thanks in advance

Adam

Comment: Does task_id have a pattern?

Comment: Regular expressions do come in different flavors - see the left hand side of regex101.com for example flavors. Please provide a specific regular expression flavor, details  on what you have tried so far (code!) and how your attempts have not worked as desired. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why would you want to use regex in this case since you're dealing with json. It's unlikely that the language you're using would not have a support / library for json, which would allow you to extract the task_id.

Getting back to regex you could try capturing a group.

```
:"(.*?)"
```

Comment: Changed your expression a bit (no need to escape everything, made it lazy additionally) and prettified the code block - if this is not what you wanted, please edit your answer again. See a demo: https://regex101.com/r/nbvaKe/1

Comment: Thank you Jan that one is better.